# Tuvan Throat singing: Get overtones louder in sygyt style

Tags: voice, overtones

I've been practicing Tuvan throat singing, especially the Sygyt style and I am able to reliably create a range of overtones. However, I have the feeling that they are of rather low volume compared to the undertone. Any pointers on how to get the overtones louder and/or the undertone more quiet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exercises for Tuvan Throat-Singing (Overtone-Singing)?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4647/exercises-for-tuvan-throat-singing-overtone-singing)